# @font-face strange behaviour in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, fonts, font-face

I'm having a strange problem with @font-face in Firefox and Chrome. It appears that the font is displaying correctly on the index page and any page directly linked from the index page. However as soon as I visit a page from the index page and then click a link in that page, the font is broken in the new page.

If that's a bit hard to follow then the site address is http://www.sungblue.com.
Font displays fine on the home page.
If I click weddings on the menu bar then the font is fine in that page also.
However if i go into the 'common questions' page from the weddings page then font is broken.

I can't understand why this is happening as I've checked all code and it's the same across all pages, any ideas why this only affects some pages?

This is how my @font-face code looks:

```
@font-face 
{
font-family: 'elron';
src: url('http://www.sungblue.com/Fonts/Elron/elronmonospace-webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
src: url('http://www.sungblue.com/Fonts/Elron/elronmonospace-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
     url('http://www.sungblue.com/Fonts/Elron/elronmonospace-webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
     url('http://www.sungblue.com/Fonts/Elron/elronmonospace-webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
     url('http://www.sungblue.com/Fonts/Elron/elronmonospace-webfont.svg#svgelron') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Any suggestions you have are very welcome. Thanks

Dan

Comment: off topic, but i think your fade transitions need to be somewhat quicker on your site ^^

Comment: @Dan Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you have is the URL. When you are in the home page or directly under that, the URL is:

```
http://www.sungblue.com/weddings.html
```

Where as in the Common Questions, the URL is **without www**:

```
http://sungblue.com/weddingfaq.html
```

Try to standardise the `www.sungblue` and `sungblue` links using either `.htaccess` or internal redirect. The same **Common Questions** page **works**, if you use the below link:

```
http://www.sungblue.com/weddingfaq.html
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Praveen! Can't believe that it was something that simple, are firefox and chrome really that fussy about fonts coming from the same domain as the rest of the page? Anyway good practice to standardise the links that I use, should've noticed that before!